# How can I ask for a full-time position before my internship ends?

Tags: job-search, internship, applications

I have been working as an intern at a company for around 2 months. I've greatly enjoyed working there and would like to continue working for them full time. However, my internship is scheduled to conclude in just two weeks.

Some of my coworkers have mentioned that there is an open position in my current department, which they believe I would be a good fit for. They've mentioned that they appreciate my help in the department and would like to see me stay beyond the originally scheduled 2 months.

I talked to my manager last week about applying for a full-time position, which he assured me that he would look into. However, as my internship's end date draws closer and closer, I worry that my chance for a full-time job may be slipping away.

**How can I ask for a full-time position before my internship ends?**

Comment: Talk to HR? Also remind hi - he may have forgot

Comment: Just remind your manager that your internship is ending soon and that you are still interested in the full-time position, if he thinks you are a good fit for it. Maybe suggest you can talk to the HR about the process if he would like to go forward with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Follow up with  your manager again. Ask specifically what would be involved with applying for the position or who you should talk to.

When you want something, it's best to be proactive rather than relying on others. So if your manager isn't trying very hard, approach HR yourself.